# Как сделать sprite во весь экран?

Tags: c#, unity3d, спрайт

Как сделать sprite во весь экран (Независимую размерность, унив?

Comment: что вы именно пытаетесь сделать? UI ? там даже скрипт не нужен

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я так понял речь идет о *Canvas / Image*

Если вручную выставлять, без *C#* скрипта, то:

- У компонента `RectTransform` надо выбрать preset:`stretch` (нижний правый угол)

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Поставить:

  1. Позиции `Left/Top/Right/Bottom` в ноль
  2. Anchors minX = minY = 0, maxX = maxY = 1
  3. Pivot для  X и Y поставить равным 0.5

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же через скрипт, то будет примерно так:

```
public RectTransform panelRectTransform;

void Start() {
    panelRectTransform.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 0);
    panelRectTransform.anchorMax = new Vector2(1, 1);
    panelRectTransform.pivot = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
    // и прочие атрибуты установить если надо
}
```

Вообще по *UI* неплохо почитать о нём и в том числе о:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchorMin.html http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchorMax.html http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-pivot.html

видео https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/rect-transform?playlist=17111